# Child wpf window above parent window

Tags: wpf

I have WPF application with main window. I want to create child WPF window which always must be above ONLY parent window. If I set TopMost property for new window then window is above ALL nonTopMost windows on desktop. It's not what I want.

Answer (score 13):

Set the Owner property of the child window so that it refers to the parent window.

```
child.Owner = parent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of the window, I often use a "Fake" window that is really just a layer in the parent along with a partailly transparent grey layer between that makes the parent look ghosted while the child is active. You can then keep the child window set to collapsed until it is needed.